# Netbeans 8.0.2 + Laravel - Multiple errors when creating project

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, netbeans-8

I haven't been able to configure Netbeans 8 and Laravel correctly. Whenever I try to create a new php file all my syntax is highlighted as in the following image:

[image]

The same happens when I create simple PHP file (not in Laravel project)

I have so far:

- Installed Composer
- Downloaded from command line
- Updated path environment variables
- created new blog in laravel
- Modified permissions to files under the bootdstrap/cache and storage folders
- Downloaded Laravel IDE helper from:
  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Yet I still get errors such like 'unable to parse file' and the following error 
in phpunit/php-token-stream/tests/fixture/class_with_method_that_declares_anonymous_class2.php

[image]

My PHP version is 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9 and I'm using Wamp. I would very much appreciate any input on this so as to try to resolve it without having to switch IDEs. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have valid IDE settings? Why Eclipse think PHP files are HTML files? What if you create plain PHP file (not in Laravel project)?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek same thing happens if i create a php file in a non-laravel project in netbeans. I updated the IDE yesterday and have not been able to use it since. I believe the issue is IDE settings but I certainly don't know which settings to edit. Thanks!

Comment: I remove `Laravel` tags then, it's IDE settings issue (or bug)